# Как работает implicitly_wait в selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Всем привет!

Читаю [документацию](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) и не могу понять, как работает implicitly_wait. Ну и плюс не совсем понимаю как работает последовательность запуска действий в Selenium.

Вопрос 1: если не ставить искусственные задержки, то webdriver будет запускать все процессы non-stop и все развалится(например не ставить задержку после создания драйвера ***driver = webdriver.Firefox()*** )?

Вопрос 2: как именно работает строка ***driver.implicitly_wait(10)*** , чего она ожидает и сколько? В документации написано, что опрашивает DOM и ждет какой-то элемент? Какой именно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Команда `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` сама по себе ничего не ждет. Она конфигурирует драйвер, включая неявное ожидание для операций поиска элементов.

Вот что говорит документация:

> An implicit wait tells WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find any element (or elements) not immediately available.

Поясню на примере:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("http://someurl")
myDynamicElement = driver.find_element_by_id("myDynamicElement")
```

После того, как выполнится команда `driver.get(...)` браузер начнет загрузку страницы, потом распарcит html, создаст DOM дерево, отрендерит страницу, и запустит javascript, если он используется и т.д. Но сама программа на питоне, которая инициировала этот процесс, продолжит исполняться.

Т.е. не дожидаясь ни запроса, ни рендеринга программа будет выполнять следующую строку. А это значит, что с настройками по умолчанию, пробуя выполнить `find_element_by_id`, она скорее всего его не найдет (так как страница попросту еще не успеет загрузится или успеет, но браузер не успеет создать DOM дерево), и функция `find_element_by_id` просто бросит исключение - элемент не найден.

Если же сконфигурировать неявное ожидание с помощью `implicilty_wait` (раскомментировать строку), то функция `find_element_by_id` будет ждать до 10 секунд, если элемент не найдет и только после этого, если элемента все еще нет, бросит исключение.

Это касается не только `find_element_by_id`, но и всего семейства функций поиска `find_*`, на все время пока драйвер не закрыть или не изменить его настройки новым вызовом `implicitly_wait`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. driver.implicitly_wait(10) нужно один раз указывать и он будет действовать до закрытия браузера? изучаю по [этим урокам](https://github.com/pythontoday/selenium_python/blob/master/chromedriver/08_selenium_switch_to_window_chrome.py) там многократно запускается он, есть ли в этом смысл?

Comment: Смысла делать это многократно - нет. Эта настройка действует на время сессии, т.е. от создания объекта `driver` до вызова `quit`.