# Небольшая проблема с Селениум

Tags: javascript, python, парсер, selenium

проблема такова:
Каждый раз когда я пытаюсь достать js элемент на сайте через `find_element` у меня выдает примерно вот такое:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".sc-c4ec0fdf-0 hWXObm"}
> (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.102)

Код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://pancakeswap.finance/prediction"
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
card = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-c4ec0fdf-0 hWXObm')
print(card)
```

Comment: Возможно имя класса генерируется уникальным для каждой сессии, проверьте совпадают ли они в вашем коде и на странице, открытой селениумом. Также driver.implicitly_wait(20) скорее всего не даст вам найти нужный элемент т.к. из-за этой команды код может начать поиск до того как прогрузятся все данные из js скриптов. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1343118/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-implicitly-wait-%D0%B2-selenium

Comment: @Дмитрий Я всё проверил, проблема осталась та же

Comment: Попробуйте найти елементы запуская  javascript в селениуме https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1385154/selenium-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%be/1385177#1385177

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю, что все дело *implicitly_wait*, который вы объявили уже после запроса, а его следует объявить сразу после переменной *driver*. Обратитесь к [этому ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1343138/447730), чтобы понять как работает этот параметр.

Answer (score 0):

В `find_element` с параметром `By.CLASS_NAME` нельзя передавать несколько классов, можно только один, а у вас передается два.

Если нужно именно два, то можно искать по xpath:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='sc-c4ec0fdf-0' or @class='hWXObm']")
```