# Автоматическое управление Telegram через Selenium (Python)

Tags: html, css, selenium, telegram, автоматизация

Всем привет, пишу небольшую программу для автоматизации некоторых задач в Telegram, хотел бы уточнить как автоматизировать нажатие некоторых кнопок, пробовал разные методы поиска кнопок, по классу, по имени, но Selenium пишет что элемент на странице отсутствует, может кто-нибудь помочь? Есть ли у кого-нибудь примеры? Кнопки которые нужно кликнуть на фото[image: Фото], также просьба использование библиотек Telethon и тому подобные не предлагать, нужна работа конкретно с Selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import keyboard
url = "https://web.telegram.org"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\я\\Desktop\\Bot\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
if keyboard.is_pressed('f1'):
    p = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-icon tgico-more rp btn-menu-toggle").click()
```

Comment: Покажите код, который не работает.

Comment: p = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-icon tgico-more rp btn-menu-toggle").click()

Comment: Во-первых, этого мало. Покажите код начиная с того, как делается переход на страницу. Во-вторых, это нужно добавить в текст вопроса, а не в комментарий

Comment: Уже добавил код в вопрос

Comment: Вероятнее всего проблема в асинхронности. Прочитайте этот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1135231/218971

Comment: Причина проблемы такая же как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1387881/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%a1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%83%d0%bc/1390811#1390811 поиск по имени класса можно делать только для одного класса, а вы передаете несколько через пробел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте поиск по xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/button/div[2]')
```

В инспекторе браузера жмёте правой кнопкой мыши по нужному элементу, и копируете его xpath

[image: как скопировать xpath]

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло