# В чем отличие явного ожидания от неявного? Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Может мне кто-нибудь объяснить чем в selenium отличается явное ожидание `WebDriverWait()` от неявного `implicitly_wait()` ? Желательно максимально детально и развернуто, с примерами, где лучше использовать одно, а где другое. Доку, естественно, читал.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1343118/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-implicitly-wait-%D0%B2-selenium

Answer (score 1):

Ну тут тот самый случай когда дьявол кроется в деталях.

И то и другое ожидание, но явные ожидания более гибкие штоли

Неявные ожидания отрабатывают по факто того, что элемент появился в DOM ему этого будет достаточно, при этом этот элемент еще может не стать к этому моменту кликабельным, видимым и тд

Явные ожидания такие проблемы решают, то есть ты можешь задать более тонкие настройки, подождать появления не только самого элемента, но условно сказать "не кликать по этой кнопке, пока она не станет кликабельной"

Вывод: хорошим тоном на сложных проектах использовать явные ожидания!