# Как сделать выбор в выпадающем меню с помощью selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

Пробую `pytest` в сочетании с selenium. Весь код работает до момента выбора в меню выбора региона. После открытия списка, либо происходит `assert Регион не сменился на Камчатский`, либо, когда пробовал другие методы (допустим c помощью `By.LINK_TEXT`) происходит ошибка `no such element: Unable to locate element`. Как заставить selenium кликнуть на Камчатский край?

[image: Мой код]
[image: То что должно быть выбрано]
[image: Структура сайта до списка]

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

@pytest.fixture
def browser():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    yield driver
    driver.quit()

def test_scenario2(browser):
    browser.get('https://sbis.ru/')
    contacts_link = browser.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Контакты").click() # переход на вкладку контакты
    assert browser.current_url == "https://sbis.ru/contacts", "Не было перехода на вкладку контакты"
    
    """
    Видимо настройки браузера (или чё-то в нём, кроме расширений) могут влиять на автоопределение региона
    """
    sleep(4)
    assert browser.current_url == "https://sbis.ru/contacts/02-respublika-bashkortostan?tab=clients", "Вкладка контакты не загрузилась или регион не Башкирия"
    
    partners = browser.find_element(By.ID, "contacts_list")
    assert partners is not None, "Партнёров нет"

    region = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "sbis_ru-Region-Chooser").click()
    sleep(10)
    # LINK_TEXT не работает
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='41 Камчатский край']").click()
    assert browser.current_url == "https://sbis.ru/contacts/41-kamchatskij-kraj?tab=clients", "Регион не сменился на Камчатский"
    sleep(5)
```

Comment: Код и ошибки лучше предоставлять в виде текста, а не изображения

Comment: Комментирование кода следует делать, используя символ #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(5) # Устанавливаем базовое ожидание
driver.get('https://sbis.ru/contacts/02-respublika-bashkortostan?tab=clients')

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'sbis_ru-Region-Chooser__text').click() # Клик на меню выбора региона
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[title="Камчатский край"]').click() # Клик на "Камчатский край"
```

Если у тега есть какой-то нестандартный селектор, его можно найти через

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[имя_атрибута="значение"]')
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, ещё 1 небольшой вопрос, в данном случае `driver.implicitly_wait(5)` означает ожидание при каждом переходе на новую страницу, клике и т.п. или  же только единожды как в случае с `sleep(5)`?

Comment: driver.implicitly_wait(время) настраивает драйвер так, чтобы он давал какое-то время на выполнение команд. К примеру, поиск кнопки. Если не нашёл - ищет ещё в течение этого времени, а не роняет исключение.  Настраивается один раз и действует до закрытия сессии.
На SO есть вопрос на данную тему - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1343118/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-implicitly-wait-%D0%B2-selenium

Comment: Если данный ответ помог решить вашу проблему, вы можете пометить его как "решение", нажав на галочку слева от ответа